# Why does Matlab gives different value than C++

Tags: c++, matlab, floating-point, precision

I am creating a huge program in c++ for computer vision, and for debugging purposes I use Matlab. After time fighting with it I realised that some simple arithmetic equation's answer is different when using Matlab and c++ (Visual studio 9 compiler BTW). why is that?

Here is the arithmetic operation:

**Matlab** function:

```
function [x,y]=shape_fun(p,shape,Ax,Ay)

x=p(1)+Ax+shape(1)+Ax.*shape(3)+Ay.*shape(4)+Ax.*Ax.*shape(5)/2+Ay.*Ay.*shape(6)/2+Ax.*Ay.*shape(7);
y=p(2)+Ay+shape(2)+Ax.*shape(8)+Ay.*shape(9)+Ax.*Ax.*shape(10)/2+Ay.*Ay.*shape(11)/2+Ax.*Ay.*shape(12);

end
```

**C++** function

```
cv::Point2d deformed(const double shape_fun[12],const cv::Point2d p,const double Ax,const double Ay){
    cv::Point2d result;

    result.x=(p.x+Ax)+shape_fun[0]+shape_fun[2]*Ax+shape_fun[3]*Ay+shape_fun[4]*Ax*Ax/2*shape_fun[5]*Ay*Ay/2+shape_fun[6]*Ax*Ay;
    result.y=(p.y+Ay)+shape_fun[1]+shape_fun[7]*Ax+shape_fun[8]*Ay+shape_fun[9]*Ax*Ax/2*shape_fun[10]*Ay*Ay/2+shape_fun[11]*Ax*Ay;
    return result;

}
```

**Data:**

Note: Matlab values are copy-pasted from debbuger c++ values, they are EXACTLY the same.

```
Ax=-12
Ay=-12
p=[468,683];
shape=[
     63.178114688537441
     36.536135487588474

    -0.038695673779030673
    -0.045313362559036965

     0.016469896824803026
     0.0017122284868442948
    -0.0030285669997117204

    -0.067902655024060773
     0.17995980761526389

     0.012716871878336870
    -0.036890386929202310
    -0.00081243692842574420
];
```

results:

**Matlab**:

```
x =
     3.947029931219995e+02
y =
     7.043339656551383e+02
```

**C++:**

```
result  {x=393.54007007383439 y=703.64248713855773 }    cv::Point_<double>
```

*Note:* I am not tagging the question as `OpenCV` on purpose. While evidently I am using `OpenCV` in C++, `cv::Point2d` is just a struct with two `double` variables, x and y, and I don't think this question is about `OpenCV` at all.

Comment: First, make your arithmetic at least borderline legible. Please.

Comment: Just to confirm: You are worried about the small difference, not about the factor 100 vs e+02 right?

Comment: I think some of your * should be + (or the other way around). Look at the formulas closely, they are not the same.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: What factor 100? _(hint: `e+02`)_

Comment: agreed, looks like your formulas are not the same....

Comment: Let me check, but I think they are just "least borderline legible"

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Well, they're not, and that's almost certainly the reason that you made and couldn't spot typos in them.

Comment: Yeah, the result is that after hours looking for correctness in the formulas, I failed. Need to go to the doctor. Oculist or Psiquiatrist?

Comment: Depends. What kind of doctor gives you a prescription for extra `'\n'`s?

Comment: @us2012 Aaaghh... right in the formating.

Comment: The funny thing is that I wrote the Matlab function from the C++ function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
result.x=
    (p.x+Ax)+
    shape_fun[0]+
    shape_fun[2]*Ax+
    shape_fun[3]*Ay+
    shape_fun[4]*Ax*Ax/2*
    shape_fun[5]*Ay*Ay/2+
    shape_fun[6]*Ax*Ay;
result.y=
    (p.y+Ay)+
    shape_fun[1]+
    shape_fun[7]*Ax+
    shape_fun[8]*Ay+
    shape_fun[9]*Ax*Ax/2*
    shape_fun[10]*Ay*Ay/2+
    shape_fun[11]*Ax*Ay;
```

should be (presumably)

```
result.x=
    (p.x+Ax)+
    shape_fun[0]+
    shape_fun[2]*Ax+
    shape_fun[3]*Ay+
    shape_fun[4]*Ax*Ax/2+ /** change here **/
    shape_fun[5]*Ay*Ay/2+
    shape_fun[6]*Ax*Ay;
result.y=
    (p.y+Ay)+
    shape_fun[1]+
    shape_fun[7]*Ax+
    shape_fun[8]*Ay+
    shape_fun[9]*Ax*Ax/2+ /** change here **/
    shape_fun[10]*Ay*Ay/2+
    shape_fun[11]*Ax*Ay;
```

Comment: No, it should be in a `for` loop instead, definitely.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't be ridiculous, this **must** be solved using Python.

Comment: Wish I could do an extra +1 for the reformatting. This is how the OP should have done it.

Comment: Dude, I have been looking at the formulas for hours, FOR HOURS! I need to go to the oculist.